# Why is "When did Mary graduate college?" considered wrong in TOEFL test?

Tags: word-usage

Ok, check this online [Toefl test page](https://www.4tests.com/exam/toefl/0/35095474),

> Question: When did Mary ____ college?
>
> Answer:
>
> A) graduate
>
> B) graduate from (TOEFL thinks B is correct)
>
> C) graduating
>
> D) graduating from

I checked [Oxford dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/graduate_2),

> [intransitive, transitive] to get a degree, especially your first
>   degree, from a university or college
>
> **graduate (in something)** Only three students graduated in Czech studies
>   last year.
>
> **graduate (from…)** She graduated from Harvard this year.
>
> He graduated from York with a degree in Psychology.
>
> **graduate something** (North American English) She graduated college last
>   year.

According to the dictionary, it seems that we use "**graduate from**" with specific universities or colleges & we use "**graduate college**" when we say "to graduate college" generally without knowing the specific one.

So, Why is "**When did Mary graduate college?**" considered wrong in TOEFL test?

Comment: I noticed that the dictionary notes that the usage without _from_ is _North American_. I'm guessing that means that it's not common, or it's strange, in non-North American English. So I'm guessing further that the test prefers the usage with _from_ since it is acceptable wherever.  But you're right to be suspicious. The usage without _from_ is acceptable, at least in North American English.

Answer (score 1):

[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/graduate) would appear to disagree with the test.  "When did Mary graduate college?" is common usage in AmE, and M-W even seems to prefer it (their definition (transitive) is *"to be graduated from"*, so adding another "from" would be equivalent to "When did Mary become graduated from from college?".  Their usage example:

> joined the navy after graduating high school

No "from".  The intransitive form doesn't even require "college"; *"to receive an academic degree or diploma"*: "graduated with honors"

You are free to specify where graduation occurred, in which case you can use "from", but "college", in the generic usage, can just be tacked on as a descriptor of what "graduated" refers to.

Answer (score 0):

> When did Mary graduate college?

although is understandable, technically one can not

> graduate college

But Mary, herself

> graduated college

and she "*graduated from*" somewhere.